# Making system2 use a specific version of python

Tags: r

I have both python2 and python3 installed on my desktop. If I do
`python -V` in the terminal I get `Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)`.

However if I use the `system2` command from R

`system2("python", args = "-V")`

then it reports `Python 2.7.10`

If I specify the full path it I get the right version

`system2("//anaconda/bin/python", args = "-V")`

`Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)`

But I'd like system2 to just use python3 by default. Is there someway to change which version it uses? This is for Mac OSX

Comment: What's the output of `Sys.which('python')`?

Comment: `"/usr/bin/python"` which is my python2 installation

Comment: which shell program are you using in terminal?

Comment: I'm using bash.

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of how `sh` finds an executable, but the difference here is because `system2` passes its first argument to a `sh` shell, not a `bash` shell. On my system, they find `python` in the same directory, but on yours it appears they do not. You could confirm by entering the command `/bin/sh` in terminal, and then in a `sh` shell running `which python` or `type -a python`.

Comment: So by running `/bin/sh` and then `which python` I still got `//anaconda/bin/python`. Running `type -a python` gave 3 results: 

`python is //anaconda/bin/python`, 

`python is /usr/bin/python`, 

`python is /usr/local/bin/python1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running R from the R application or RStudio, system calls access a different environment than they do when you run R from terminal. Because of that, the `PATH` environment variable you have configured to run the correct version of a unix executable in a shell program is different than  the one used in a `system2()`or `system()` call in an R session in either of these applications.  To solve this, you need to set the path in your R environment.

In an interactive session, you can do this:

```
# Reproducing your problem (in the R application or RStudio)
system2("python", args="-V")
# Python 2.7.10

# set a new PATH in the environment accessed by R
# This is the line you can also add to your .Rprofile
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(c("//anaconda/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), 
                        collapse = .Platform$path.sep))
# For users other than the OP, you'll want to use the directory
# where your preferred installation of python is. For the OP that's
# //anaconda/bin

# Confirm
system2("python", args="-V")
# Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)
```

The system command `python` should now be found in the directory `//anaconda/bin`, rather than `/usr/bin`.  This, of course, depends on where these unix executables are found in your system, so for readers other than the OP, you'll need to use the directory that holds your desired version of `python`.

This `PATH` will remain valid through the rest of your R session. To change your path in all R sessions, update (or create, if you haven't yet) your `.Rprofile` file. An `.Rprofile` file can be (or go) in your `HOME` directory or `R_HOME`. If you add the above line to `.Rprofile`, each time R is initialized, they will execute at the beginning of each R session.

Comment: This worked great. Although could you update your answer to not assign a value to `PATH` and instead just use `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in your second call? Otherwise if its in `.Rprofile` it'll put `PATH` into the environment unless you also put some code to clean it up

Comment: @ConorNeilson if you just set `PATH=/path/to/python3/installation`, R system calls won't have access to any executables not in that path. This will solve your python problem, but cause others. Generally, you don't want to do this. This is why you add things to PATH rather than replacing it, and applies whether you do it in an interactive session or by setting it in your `.Rprofile`.  You can confirm this by using the code above in `.Rprofile`, running `quit()` in R, then starting a new session and checking the output of `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.

Comment: @ConnorNeilson but perhaps I misunderstood your comment. Obviously, just putting `Sys.getenv("PATH")` won't help, since it looks for `PATH` according to R's rules for where to get PATH. That command doesn't pull it from your bash profile or anything like that.

Comment: All I meant was remove the `PATH=Sys.getenv("PATH")` and replace the 2nd line with `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(c("//anaconda/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH")),
                        collapse = .Platform$path.sep))`